# How to set up pagination

Tags: pagination

This sounds simple enough but I'm finding it impossible to implement. This is my [website](http://www.thezenapproach.com), you can see that on the homepage there are post excerpts but I am only showing 15 posts out of about 25 by using the "get posts" plugin with the code below. I want to show the rest on a different page using pagination.

Any ideas?

```
[tpg_get_posts category_name="archives" numberposts="15" shorten_content="w790" ]
```

Comment: TPG doesn't have a pagination option - is there a reason you're using that for your home page instead of the built-in WordPress function?  It seems odd to use a plugin to generate posts for the home page, since that's really what WordPress does by default.

Comment: I'm using it because when I used genesis teasers on my homepage the formatting was  lost, TPG though keeps the formatting.

Comment: Do you of something similar to TPG posts that supports pagination? Thanks

Comment: Short answer, no.  Realistically, since you're relying on plugins to generate your code for you, your options are either accept what the plugin gives you (and request the author to change it) or modify the plugin yourself and re-modify it every time a new version comes out.  Alternately, you could find a different excerpt plugin that supports formatting - this link is a bit outdated, but it's a good starting point to help you find what you're looking for.  http://franklinbishop.net/excerpt-plugins-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I would take that shortcode out, go to Admin -> Settings -> Reading, set "Front Page displays your latest posts", and set "Blog pages show at most 15 posts".

Comment: That might work for the homepage but I probably should have mentioned that all my pages are set up like that so I would like pagination for all the pages.

Comment: It will do that for all blog-type pages - archive, category, etc - not just the home page.